# Can I resume an interrupted download of Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

I have a slow internet connection. I want to download Mountain Lion (Mac OS X 10.8) from the Mac App Store and resume the download if it gets interrupted because of my internet connection.

Does the Mac App Store allow resuming broken downloads?

Answer (score 7):

Yes - the App store handles interrupted purchases without intervention in most cases. There is a [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4485) if you want to nudge things or it manages to wedge itself.

You don't have to let the download complete on iOS or Mac OS X and can control things on the Mac side of the store much better than on iOS.

Comment: I've also noticed that when you switch from wifi to ethernet, the Mac App Store automatically continues to download via ethernet.

Comment: As well, you can click on the app icon that's downloading in Launch Center to pause it.

Comment: i've tried it and it completed about 25% downloads then i puased. when i've resumed it started from beginning! crap!

Answer (score 2):

The Mac App Store does allow to resume a download, however things do not seem to work out always as expected - to be safe download it all in one piece.

Yesterday, I downloaded Mountain Lion from the Mac App Store - halted it - and resumed later without having restarted the Mac. **The whole download started over.** This is not the first time I have encountered it - therefore I do not take the pause/resume feature for granted.

[image]  [image]