# Can I pause the Mountain Lion download and resume it later?

Tags: mac-appstore

My internet service provider has its own broadband portal and the session lasts only 12 hours after which I need to relogin.  While relogging the download of the Mountain Lion gets interrupted because the connection resets.

I'd like to take my Mac to my friend's house for increased net speed. Will the download be resumed or do I have to start downloading all the way from the beginning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I resume an interrupted download of Mac OS X Mountain Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57361/can-i-resume-an-interrupted-download-of-mac-os-x-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for that, and No, you can't, it has to be downloaded in one time only. If you paused; it'll restart from the beginning.

This is the source from Apple Discussions:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4139031

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd seriously consider getting a better connection if possible. I don't see how your provider gets away with calling something that can't download 4GB in 12 hours 'broadband'.

Mountain Lion downloads from the Mac App Store can't be resumed.

As such I see two options:

1. Take your Mac to a store/friend and get them to download it for you.
2. As a last resort, download it from unofficial sources which support resuming.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes that long, ie; you probably live in a country with slow broadband connections, go to an Apple Store and they will download and install it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally hit pause on my Mac Mini and it did pick up from where it had paused, only about thirty seconds went by before I realized I had paused it, I was right in the middle of the download.